# Userform VLookup

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have a Userform in which a number of Text Boxes need to be updated from values on a spreadsheet based on a condition.  I'm trying to use vlookup to accomplish this.  The user selects a name in Combobox Name1 and then the userform should populate the following based on that name in the combobox

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Name1_AfterUpdate()
'Lookup Values based on first control

    Me.DateEnc = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.Name1, Caselist.Range("Lookup"), 0, 0)
    Me.Status = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((Me.Name1), Caselist.Range("Lookup"), 0, 2)
    Me.LastDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((Me.Name1), Caselist.Range("Lookup"), 0, 3)
    Me.Phone = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((Me.Name1), Caselist.Range("Lookup"), 0, 5)
    Me.Address = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup((Me.Name1), Caselist.Range("Lookup"), 0, 6)

End Sub
```

I'm getting the following error: "Runtime Error 424, Object Required", and then the debug mode is highlighting this line:

```
Me.DateEnc = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.Name1, Caselist.Range("Lookup"), 0, 0)
```

There must be something wrong with my formatting here.  Oh, "Lookup" is a dynamic range that uses the following formula:

=OFFSET(Caselist!$A$3,,,COUNTA(Caselist!$A$3:$A$500),9)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?  Thanks so much for responding

Comment: Try Sheets("Castlist").Range

Comment: Your 3rd and 4th arguments are the wrong way around

Comment: Yeah I was using VLookup wrong.  Changed it to .DateEnc = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.Name1, Sheets("Caselist").Range("Lookup"), 1, 0).  All the other ones are correctly specifying columns now too.  

I tried Sheets("Caselist").Range but that caused a VLookup error

Comment: Still having the same problem

Comment: @DustinBurns A) Try using just a variable instead of .DateEnc and a value instead of Me.Name1, e.g. a = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Dustin, Sheets("Caselist").Range("Lookup"), 1, 0).   

B) On a separate worksheet try =vlookup(Dustin, Lookup, 1, 0) and see what returns

Comment: Check data type for "Me.Name1"